# Vue Component text only partially passes to slot, the rest appears in outer div

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I have a wrapping formatting vue component with a slot, and two components that use it.  When passing a list structure it works fine, as it does when using the wrapping div directly, but it fails when trying to pass a simple string.  The first word of the string renders as expected, but the rest appears in the opening div.  I've tried wrapping the mustached prop in additional html tags, but the content still doesn't render correctly.

**Display Text component**

```
<template>
  <two-col-row-display
    :field="field"
    :fieldcss="fieldcss"
    :valuecss="valuecss"
  >
    {{ value }}
  </two-col-row-display>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
          field: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
          fieldcss: {
            type: String,
          },
          value: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
          },
          valuecss: {
            type: String,
          },
        },
    }
</script>
```

**Two column row display wrapper component**

```
<template>
  <div class="gridwrap">
    <div class="row field" :class="fieldcss">
      {{ field + ':' }}
    </div>
    <div class="row value" :class="valuecss">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
          field: {
            type: String,
          },
          fieldcss: {
            type: String,
          },
          valuecss: {
            type: String,
          },
        },
    }
</script>
```

**Display Text used**

```
<display-text
    field="Description"
    value={{ $recipe->description }}
></display-text>
```

But it outputs only the first part of the description "All" where it should.  The rest of the description "of the recipe" gets output as an attribute of the wrapping div.
**Output html**

```
<div class="gridwrap" of the recipe>
    <div class="row field"> Description: </div>
    <div class="row value"> All </div>
</div>
```

Using the wrapping component directly works as expected, but I don't want to use that component directly.

```
<two-col-row-display
    field="Description???"
  >{{ $recipe->description }}
</two-col-row-display>
```

outputs the desired result for the display-text component

```
<div class="gridwrap">
    <div class="row field"> Description???: </div>
    <div class="row value">All of the recipe </div>
</div>
```

How can I modify the display-text component to render the text in the slot correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I neglected to wrap the data passed to the value prop in quotes.  The display text component should be filled out like:

```
<display-text
    field="Description"
    value="{{ $recipe->description }}"
></display-text>
```